# qml delegate cannot create binding with ListModel when ListModel isEmpty and append an empty jsobject at first time

Tags: qt, qml

I have a repeater like this:

```
    Repeater {
       id: idRepeater
       model: fruitModel
       delegate: Rectangle {
         id:idRect
         width:20
         height:20
         color:sColor
       }
    }
```

My model has nothing, like this:

```
    ListModel {
        id: fruitModel
    }
```

All I want is that I can add element by ListModel's `append(jsobject dict)` API. 
I write code below:

```
fruitModel.append({});
fruitModel.append({"sColor":"yellow"});
```

But the second rectangle is not yellow. why?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to model data like:

```
ListModel {
        id: fruitModel
        dynamicRoles: true
    }

Repeater {
       id: idRepeater
       model: fruitModel
       delegate: Rectangle {
         id:idRect
         width:20
         height:20
         color: model.sColor
       }
    }
```

You should also set [dynamicRoles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#dynamicRoles-prop) to `true` for your list model when members of each object are different.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it still not work yet. I found **If the model is a model object (such as a ListModel) the delegate can access all model roles as named properties** in the **Repeater QML Type** document. I modify my code from `fruitModel.append({});
fruitModel.append({"sColor":"yellow"});` to `fruitModel.append({"sColor":""});
fruitModel.append({"sColor":"yellow"});`. It works now. But I don't know why -.-